# Apply condition to MySQL as a result of IF statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a query:

```
SELECT campaign_id, campaign_balance, campaign_email
FROM campaigns
WHERE campaign_unique = 0
LIMIT 1
```

But I only want to apply the `WHERE campaign_unique = 0` condition to the above query when the following returns a one:

```
SELECT COUNT(earning_id) FROM earnings WHERE earning_ip = '77.166.56.152' LIMIT 1
```

Is there some way I can apply an IF statement to decide whether or not to apply a WHERE condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply if() in WHERE like this:

```
SELECT 
    campaign_id, campaign_balance, campaign_email
FROM campaigns
WHERE
    campaign_unique = if (some_condition, campaign_unique, 0)
LIMIT 1
```

This means following: if some_condition is evaluated to TRUE, than WHERE condition whould be campaign_unique = campaign_unique (or not apply condition at all), and if it evaluated to FALSE, than WHERE condition whould be campaign_unique = 0.
So, for you case, it whould something like this:

```
SELECT
    campaign_id, campaign_balance, campaign_email
FROM campaigns
WHERE
    campaign_unique = if (
        (SELECT COUNT(earning_id) FROM earnings WHERE earning_ip = '77.166.56.152' LIMIT 1) = 1, 
        campaign_unique, 
        0
    )
LIMIT 1
```

Or store result of subquery in variable to simplify query:

```
SET @earningsCount = (SELECT COUNT(earning_id) FROM earnings WHERE earning_ip = '77.166.56.152' LIMIT 1);

SELECT
    campaign_id, campaign_balance, campaign_email
FROM campaigns
WHERE
    campaign_unique = if (
        @earningsCount = 1,
        campaign_unique,
        0
    )
LIMIT 1
```